# How to show child of parent in template?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Category',null=True, blank=True)
    cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cat_overview = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    cat_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    sub_cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='SubCategory',null=True, blank=True)
    sub_cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_cat_overview = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sub_cat_parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_cat_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class SubSubCategory(models.Model):
    subsub_cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    subsub_cat_parent = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    subsub_cat_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

I already filled these models with some data and I have no problem showing `Category` model in templates but there is a problem when I want to show `SubCategory` and `SubSubCategory` simultaneously in one template.

[image]

these are the categories, but when I click on "Python" for instance. This pages shows up:

[image]

the problem as you can see in above code is that only `python syntax`, `Python Variables` and `Python loops` belongs to `Python Basic` not `Python Files` and `Python Logs`. How do I avoid this and show only related `SubSubCategory` instances of `SubCategory` model?

Codes associated to above image:

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'tutorials/home.html', {'categories':Category.objects.all()})


def sub_cat(request, category):
    sub_cats = SubCategory.objects.filter(sub_cat_parent__cat_slug=category)
    subsub_cats = SubSubCategory.objects.filter(subsub_cat_parent__sub_cat_parent__cat_slug = category)

    context = {
        'sub_cats': sub_cats,
        'subsub_cats': subsub_cats,
    }
    return render(request, 'tutorials/sub_cat.html', context)
```

and `sub_cat.html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="sidenav">
                {% for sub_cat in sub_cats %}
                        <button class="dropdown-btn"> {{ sub_cat.sub_cat_title }} 
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-container">
                                {% for subsub_cat in subsub_cats %}
                                        <a href="#">{{ subsub_cat.subsub_cat_title }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>Learn Python</h2>
        <p>
        Authoritatively ....
        </p>
</div>
```

Please help me with this thank you.

edit: If you know a better way other this method, so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting all the `SubSubCategory` instances and using them twice you should use the reverse relation:

```
{% for subsub_cat in sub_cat.subsubcategory_set.all %}
    <a href="#">{{ subsub_cat.subsub_cat_title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more about reverse relation in the [Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much @ikkuh, it is a nice approach.